# why two pointers used in structure in c

Tags: c

I read those about tree in c:

```
struct node
{
  int key_value;
  struct node *left;
  struct node *right;
};

/* insert a value to tree */
insert(int key, struct node **leaf)
{
    if( *leaf == 0 )
    {
        *leaf = (struct node*) malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
        (*leaf)->key_value = key;
        /* initialize the children to null */
        (*leaf)->left = 0;    
        (*leaf)->right = 0;  
    }
    else if(key < (*leaf)->key_value)
    {
        insert( key, &(*leaf)->left );
    }
    else if(key > (*leaf)->key_value)
    {
        insert( key, &(*leaf)->right );
    }
}
```

I can't understand here: insert(int key, struct node **leaf) why two pointers **leaf, does *leaf ok? I am confused when to use two pointers.pls help, thank you very much!

Comment: It's a pointer to a `struct node*`.

Comment: This looks like a binary tree, and if so, your left and right nodes or "leafs" are the child branches.

Comment: **note:** **leaf; it's not called "two pointer". it's called "pointer to pointer"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `insert(int key, struct node **leaf)` you are Passing the Address pointed by `*leaf` by C version of "Pass By Reference". And in `insert(int key, struct node *leaf)` you are passing the Address pointed by `*leaf` by `Pass By Value` method.Note C Parameter are always Passed by Value.

So, In This particular Case it doesn't matter if you use `insert(int key, struct node **leaf)` or `insert(int key, struct node *leaf)` both will achieve the same outputs.The only difference in this case is that in `insert(int key, struct node **leaf)` your passing the address by C version of Pass by Reference and in `insert(int key, struct node *leaf)` your passing the address by `Pass By Value` method.

Example Code A,

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct node
{
   int data;
};

void AddFive(struct node **t);

int main()
{
   struct node *n = NULL;
   n = new node;
   n->data = 5;
   printf("%d\n", n->data);
   AddFive(&n);
   printf("%d\n", n->data);

   return 0;
}

void AddFive(struct node **t)
{
    (*t)->data = (*t)->data+5;
}
```

Example Code B,

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct node
{
   int data;
};

void AddFive(struct node *t);

int main()
{
   struct node *n = NULL;
   n = new node;
   n->data = 5;
   printf("%d\n", n->data);
   AddFive(n);
   printf("%d\n", n->data);

   return 0;
}

void AddFive(struct node *t)
{
    t->data = t->data+5;
}
```

If you notice both Code A and Code B achieve the same output.

Answer (score 0):

C has only pass by value. If pointer to `node struct` is used as parameter then any modification to passed pointer will not be seen in the caller function. In that case you have to return a pointer from the function `insert`. Pointer to pointer is used here to update the pointer passed to function  `insert`.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to change the value of a variable defined in `main()` through some function. Think what do you do. You send the address of that variable and then using that address, change the content of that variable.

Now, in an example cases, the variable is of `int` type, so sending the address of that variable would mean in the function, you have to receive it in a variable of type `int *`

```
void test(int* var) {
    *var++;
}

int main() {
    int integer = 1;
    test(&integer);
    printf("%d", integer);
    return 0;
}
```

To change the value of the variable `integer` you send the address of that to the function `test()`.

---

Now take this same situation, and think if you need to change the content of a variable which is itself a `struct node *`. Then you send the address of that variable, and receive it with a `(struct node *)*`. Thats what is happening in the example you posted.

You want the changes that is to be made to the `leaf` variable in the `insert()` fucntion to reflect in the calling function. For this to take place you send the address and change the content accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It is call by  reference . if we have to change the value of *leaf then we should have its address thats why we used two *'s when is for pointer of leaf and other to get address of *leaf.

Answer (score 0):

Case 1:

When you are passing a address of a variable then a single pointer is enough to access the variable

Example:

```
struct node a;

func(&a); // calling
```

In the `func()` definition:

```
func(struct node *a);
```

Here a points to the address of node. And we can access `a` using its address directly.

Case 2:

When you are sending the address of pointer variable:

```
struct node *a;

func(&a); // calling
```

Then in the function definition it should use a double pointer:

```
func(struct node **a);
```